# Alternate LED controller for LED light fixture

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, led, light

My wife and I bought and installed [this light fixture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0816JKHZH) the other day.  We've been satisfied with the look, however, the LED controller and remote that came with it are absolutely awful.

We were hoping it would be possible just for us to buy our own LED controller, preferably one that works with our current LED-compatible (*Leviton*) wall dimmer-switch and let's us permanently set the color temperature (*I hate remotes*).  **Is this feasible?**

All the lights in the fixture are 3-wire and are wired in parallel, so I would expect any controller with a 3-wire setup and sufficient wattage would work, but I don't know much about what resistance they expect on the output or frequencies they operate at.

---

Edit: For clarification I am referring to changing the AC:DC converter in the fixture.

Comment: @dandavis -- triac dimmable LED drivers are definitely a thing, but you are starting to look at more architectural LED hardware for that...

Comment: @dandavis - They're certainly are.  I've got at least three lights in my house that use an external AC:DC power supply with a color temperature selection that handle external dimming.  What isn't clear is how specialized these power supplies are to the fixtures they're sold with.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: you just blew my mind. My mouth says "thanks", my wallet says "darn you"!

Comment: You will have to gut the driver from the fixture, and replace with a carefully matched (in terms of current and min/max voltage) "triac dimmable led driver" like a meanwell PCD series. It's an intermediate electronics skill level project than many wouldn't be comfortable tackling, but is do-able, aside from the color temp selection. The "hard" part is finding the DC current and voltage; are you handy with a multi-meter?

Comment: I'm an EE, I just haven't done the deep-dive into understanding the world of residential LED lighting and was curious how interchangeable the drivers are and if there are standard voltages or frequencies.

Comment: @dandavis - I guess I need to pull it apart and ring it out, but I'm curious why the LED's in the fixture are 3-wire.  I'm wondering maybe if there's two different color LED's, and the controller varies the ratio of voltages to adjust color temp?

Comment: Yes there are 2 different sets of LEDs in the fixture. Some 'cool' blue-white ones and some 'warm' orange-white ones. The ratio of currents to them are varied to set the color temperature.

Comment: the controler varies the _current_ between the two to control color temp, but I don't see a way to do that from the wall dimmer replacement, so you'll likely have to choose between all on on one color. Or I guess you could try driving both in parallel and hope they have the same efficacy and current requirements; perhaps a power resistor could be used on one side to slightly adjust (lower) current if needed to hard-code a certain ratio, but it won't be adjustable anymore unless you hand-roll some pretty fancy circuits downstream of the dimmer.